# Tower of Hanoi with very specific psuedo code

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi, non-recursive

I'm trying to implement the following psuedo code:

```
place all disks in peg 0
p1 = 0 // Disk 1 is located in peg p1, which is peg 0
Loop {
move Disk 1 from peg p1 to peg (p1 + 1) % 3
p1 = (p1 + 1) % 3 // update peg location of Disk 1
p = (p1 + 1) % 3
p' = (p1 + 2) % 3
// peg p and peg p' are the two other pegs besides peg p1
if peg p and peg p' are both empty
then return // we are done with the moves
else if peg p is empty
then move the top disk in peg p' to peg p
else if peg p' is empty
then move the top disk in peg p to peg p'
else
let d = top disk of peg p
let d' = top disk of peg p'
if d < d'
then move disk d from peg p to peg p'
else move disk d' from peg p' to peg p
}
```

but I am running into problems. For example, I use a double dimensional array but get garbage in the rows and I'm not quite sure how I will keep track of which disk is on top of p and p'. Sorry for the long post but thanks in advance Here's where I've run into a wall:

```
public static void moveIt(int n, int p1, int p, int pp)
    {
        p1=0;
        int pegs[][]=new int[3][n];
        pegs[p1][0]=n;
        pegs[p][0]=0;
        pegs[pp][0]=0;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("move disk 1 from peg "+p1+" to peg "+(p1+1)%3);
            pegs[p1][0]=pegs[p1][0]-1;
            pegs[(p1+1)%3][0]=pegs[(p1+1)%3][0]-1;
            p1=(p1+1)%3;
            p=(p1+1)%3;
            pp=(p1+2)%3;
            System.out.println(pegs[p][0]);
            if((pegs[p][0]==0)&&(pegs[pp][0]==0))
                return;
            else if(pegs[p][0]==0)  
                System.out.println("move the disk "+n+" in peg "+pp+" to peg "+p);
            else if(pegs[pp][0]==0)
                System.out.println("move the top disk in peg "+p+" to peg "+pp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are n, p1, p, and pp? What is the input/output combination?

Comment: n is the number of disks, p1 begins as tower 0, p begins as tower 1, and pp begins as tower 2

Comment: are you allowed to use an arraylist? Or does it have to be an array object?

Comment: I can use an arraylist or even arrays of stacks but I didn't feel comfortable enough with syntax to use them

Comment: Take a look at stacks...they Last In First Out (LIFO) data structures and are very easy to use.  They have two operations: push and pop.  Push adds an element to the stack. Pop takes one off the stack.  You can also see if a stack isEmpty().  You should create one stack for each tower.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I ended up using stacks and based the entire code off of when p=0, p=1 and p=2. It's long and it's ugly, but it works using the given pseudo code